# Findout how much of a string matches

Tags: c#, .net, string

Say I have two Strings:

```
"SomeTextHereThatIsTheSource"
"SomeTextHereThatIsCloseToTheSourceButNotTheSame"
```

Is there a slick .net way to know what part of the text is the same (starting from the beginning).

So in this example the result would be:

```
"SomeTextHereThatIs"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use TakeWhile:

```
string MatchFromStart(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null) return "";

    var matchingArray = s1.TakeWhile((c, i) => { return i < s2.Length && c == s2[i]; });
    return String.Join("", matchingArray);
}
```

Then to use it:

```
string s1 = "SomeTextHereThatIsTheSource";
string s2 = "SomeTextHereThat";
string s3 = "SomeTextHereThatIsCloseToTheSourceButNotTheSame";
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart(s1, s2));   // SomeTextHereThat
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart(s2, s1));   // SomeTextHereThat
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart(s3, s1));   // SomeTextHereThatIs
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart("", s1));   // (blank string)
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart(s3, ""));   // (blank string)
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart(null, s1)); // (blank string)
Console.WriteLine(MatchFromStart(s2, null)); // (blank string)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say a `for` loop over the shorter string, comparing character by character is your best bet. It will probably be fastest as well.

```
// str1 is shorter or equal in length to str2:
for(int i=0; i < str1.Length; i++)
{
  if(str1[i] == str2[i])
   continue;

  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple while loop in order to determine the matching length:

```
int len = 0;
while (len < s1.Length && len < s2.Length && s1[len] == s2[len]) {
    len++;
}
```

You can improve it a little bit, if you determine the minimum length of both strings in advance

```
int minLength = Math.Min(s1.Length, s2.Length);
int len = 0;
while (len < minLength && s1[len] == s2[len]) {
    len++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the most optimized, here's a pretty clean way to go about it exploiting the fact that a `string` is also an `IEnumerable<char>`.

```
static string CommonPrefix(string string1, string string2) {
    var length = Enumerable.Zip(string1, string2, (a, b) => a == b).TakeWhile(a => a).Count();
    return string1.Substring(0, length);
}
```